# Cannot find file : xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 when geocoding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-geocoding-api

I got this error msg

> Cannot find file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Below is the code. How to resolve this issue? Appreciate your help.

```
rivate void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
 string sPath = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false";


 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(sPath));
 wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);  

     }



 void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(e.Result);

 XElement locationElement = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result").Element("geometry").Element("location");

double latitude = (double)locationElement.Element("lat");

double longitude = (double)locationElement.Element("lng");


txtBlkLatLon.Text = latitude.ToString() + "," + longitude.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
```

By

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
```

The former is trying to load data at the location specified by the string (which contains the data, not the location).

The later, is trying to directly read the data.

Comment: I tried these, still not work. BTW, is there a limit on using google geocode api service? The doc says 2500 but look at my strURL, I did not include the key.

Comment: Thanks it works. I forgot to comment out this line and other :var Xelm = XElement.Parse(e.Result); can you tell me is this google geocode api service unlimited access? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I read but there is no mention of any restriction if you dont use the key! See, my code above, I did not use key and it still getting the result from Google. Is this safe?

Comment: MilkBottle, I help you to solve an issue with the Xml handling. O have no knowledge about geocode api services. If there is another issue, create a new question so competent people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does the exception happen?

Have you tried using XDocument.Parse for creating the XDocument from string?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx

You should also attach the DownloadStringCompleted event handler **before** you call the DownloadStringAsync.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I need to use XElement method.Will check this out.